# Javascript/HTML Storage Options With File Protocol (file://)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing an HTML/JS/CSS app and would like to share it with file base. So I and my team can use it with a local HTML file (file://xxx.html). I have two separate pages (HTML files), one a shopping list and another a pantry. I want to add/mark off things from my shopping list as "bought" which will then fill up the list of items in my pantry.

I have attempted using localstorage but that seems to be domain-based and does not work well between the two files. I am looking for offline solutions as well that must keep the items added to either list saved after closing and reopening the file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no storage associated with `file://` URLs. If you can set up a simple local server, or host it on one of the various services with a free tier, that would probably be best.

To do it with just a file, you'll have to have the user explicitly load and save the file:

- Have your page load a local file by having the user drag-and-drop or select it via an `input type="file"` element.
- Allow the user to save it by generating the file text in memory and then offering it for download so they can save it locally.

This isn't great user experience, of course.

Something along these lines ([CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-danilo-6knix5?file=/main.js) — sadly, Stack Snippets don't allow download):

```html
<div>
    <label>
        Load list:
        <input id="file-load" type="file" />
    </label>
</div>
<input id="btn-save" type="button" value="Save List" />
<ul id="list"></ul>
<div>
    <label>
        Add:
        <input id="item-text" type="text" width="20" />
    </label>
    <input id="btn-add" type="button" value="Add" />
</div>
```

```js
const listElement = document.getElementById("list");
const fileInput = document.getElementById("file-load");
const saveButton = document.getElementById("btn-save");
const addButton = document.getElementById("btn-add");
const itemText = document.getElementById("item-text");

function addListItem(text) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = text;
    listElement.appendChild(li);
}

fileInput.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.files[0].text()
    .then(json => {
        const list = JSON.parse(json);
        for (const element of list) {
            addListItem(element);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert("Error loading list file!");
    });
});

saveButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const list = Array.from(
        listElement.children,
        li => li.textContent
    );
    const json = JSON.stringify(list);
    const blob = new Blob([json], {
        type: "application/json"
    });
    const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "list.json";
    link.href = objUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    setTimeout(() => {  // Older Firefox needed this
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }, 100);
});

addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const text = itemText.value.trim();
    if (text) {
        addListItem(text);
    }
    itemText.value = "";
    itemText.focus();
});
```

That's just maintaining a list of strings, but you can make it a list of objects instead, so you can have your `checked` flag, etc.)